# How to open a route in a modal dialog in ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, modal-dialog

We have a requirement of opening a modal dialog containing a route or a component. We are looking for some modal components, and saw [ember-bootstrap](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap)'s modal is useful.

So,

1. How can we open any route as a modal dialog ? (If parent route decides a route to be open in a modal, the child route should be open in modal.)
2. Can we create a service, to pop up a modal dialog? Such as: `ModalDialogService.popup(title, bodyComponent, commitHandler, cancelHandler);` or `ModalDialogService.popup(title, routeName, commitHandler, cancelHandler);` And how can we do this without violating the *Data Down Action Up* principle?
3. Is there any guide, document, tutorial or npm package for implementing modals in ember.js?

**UPDATED:**

What I need is to open any of the current routes in a modal. For example, in a given route hierarchy:

```
-module1
|-module1.query
|-module1.add
|-module1.update
|-module1.delete
```

Currently  `module1.query` has transitions to others. But I want to give an option to the module developers to open any of the *add, update, delete* routes in a modal. So that `query` route doesn't lose its state, when an *add* operation finished.

Also we have some services used by components. At some conditions, services need to display a modal that has a component.

Comment: Hi @ykaragol, something you still need here that I can help with ?

Comment: @TameBadger I've updated the question.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I just want to pick apart what you're trying a bit more. Do sortoff want two routes open at the same time ? In the way that, module1.query is currently the route, and you want to open module.add above it in a modal ? I think I have a solution if that is the case..

Comment: Yes, exactly that is. I don't want to lose query conditions, query results etc.  while adding a new item.

Comment: Ok cool, updated the answer with a new twiddle and some of the related code, just check it out and let me know if that is what you're after. You'll see I nested the add/update/delete underneath the query route, so the query route is active while you navigate between the other three. You could maybe just move query up into module1 if it's not completely necessary to have query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a service and component similar to one below to achieve what you want.

Have a look at the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/984967a29d5c7cdc430e5e878cf5fc70?openFiles=templates.components.bs-modal.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.bs-modal.hbs) for a demo of how this works exactly, and the code below for quick reference

Your route template could look something like this.

```
// templates/hasmodal.hbs

{{#bs-modal}}
   Modal Content
{{/bs-modal}}
```

Your route hooks, with service injected

```
// routes/hasmodal.js

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  modalNavigation: Ember.inject.service(),

  activate(){
    console.log('openingModal')
    this.get('modalNavigation').openModal()
  },

  deactivate(){
    console.log('closingModal')
    this.get('modalNavigation').openModal()
  },

  actions: {
    onClose(){
      console.log('we want to close route')
    }
  }
})
```

Your bs-modal or relevant component

```
//components/bs-modal.js

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  modalNavigation: Ember.inject.service(),

  isOpen: Ember.computed.alias('modalNavigation.modalOpen'),

  classNameBindings: ['isOpen:modalDialog:notOpen'],

  actions: {
    close(){
        this.get('modalNavigation').closeModal()
    }
  }
})
```

The bs-modal component template

```
// templates/components/bs-modal

<div>
   {{yield}}
</div>
<button class='close' {{action 'close'}}>Close Me</button>
```

Your Modal Service to manage state

```
// services/modal-navigation.js

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  modalOpen: false,
  openModal(){
    this.set('modalOpen',true)
  },
  closeModal(){
    this.set('modalOpen',false)
  }
})
```

**UPDATE:**

updated [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a7576bef5c81f5203b69f18363ccef07?openFiles=templates.components.modal-component.hbs)

It basically nests routes that contain a modal underneath a route you want to preserve the state of and show behind the modal.

```
// router.js [truncated]
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('module1',function(){
    this.route('query',function(){
      this.route('add')
      this.route('update', { path: '/update/:item_id' })
      this.route('delete', { path: '/delete/:item_id' })
    })
  })

// templates/modules1/query.hbs
Queried List {{link-to 'add item' 'module1.query.add'}}<br/>
<ul>
  {{#each model as |item|}}
    <li>
        {{item.id}}-{{item.title}} 
        {{link-to 'u' 'module1.query.update' item}}
        {{link-to 'd' 'module1.query.delete' item}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
{{outlet}}

// templates/module1/query/add.hbs
{{#modal-component isOpen=true onClose=(action "routeClosed")}}
    <div>
    Title:{{input value=model.title}}
  </div>
  <button {{action 'save'}}>Save</button>
{{/modal-component}}
```

Where all the other sub components follow the same modal wrapper principle

Comment: Thanks for it! That is it.

Comment: Almost a year later and this answer is still saving lives!